# Redux `connect()` return an object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I'm using these libraries:

```
react: 16.8.6
redux: 4.0.1
react-redux: 7.0.3
```

I have a simple component (Typescript):

```
import ...;  
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class ExampleComponent extends React.PureComponent<IProps, {}> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.name}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

interface IProps{
    name: string;
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        name: state.name
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ExampleComponent);
```

And I have a parent component:

```
import ExampleComponent from './ExampleComponent';

export default class App extends React.PureComponent<{}, {}> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ExampleComponent />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

For some reason the `connect(mapStateToProps)(ExampleComponent)` returns an object instead of React component.
I am getting an error:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected
>   a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object

[image]

Also when I trying to do `console.info(typeof connect(mapStateToProps)(ExampleComponent))` it prints just `object` to the console.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: use  `connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ExampleComponent)`

Comment: It didn't help. It still throws an error.

Comment: how have you imported `connect` in your file

Comment: `import { connect } from 'react-redux';` (I will add this to the question)

Comment: `connect()(Component)` should return a component. I suspect the error is caused elsewhere. Please include the full error traceback in the question. This kind of error could be caused by a typo in an import somewhere.

Comment: There is no other code in my App. It is the first time I'm using Redux. I will put the error in the question

Comment: Are you using the TS options `esModuleInterop` and `allowSyntheticDefaultImports`? I think those are required if you want to use both babel and tsc.

Comment: Please add your index.tsx file listing and include how you are importing and using `App`.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue inside a fresh `npx create-react-app my-app --typescript` and was not able to reproduce it.

Comment: It looks as though there is a type mismatch between your state object and your name prop. You haven't shown how your state object is defined in your question. Is the name variable in your state definitely a string?

Comment: Yes, it's a string. The issue says that you are trying to render an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. It was the `react-dom` library. It was mistakenly set to `16.4.XX` while `redux-dom` `connect` uses `React.memo()` method that could return an object.
But `react-dom 16.4.XX` doesn't know how to handle such objects.

Upgrading to `react-dom 16.8.XX` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

at first glance, it seems like the problem is with {this.props.name}
it is expected to be a string and getting an object for some reason.

please try to console 'name'

```
render() {
 const { name } = this.props
 console.log('name', name)

 return (
  //
 )
}
```

it's highly probable that this is the issue.

Comment: No, the issue is with the `App` component. The error says: `Check the render method of "App"`. It seems that `<ExampleComponent />` is an object and not a component.